# Class implementing Serializable cannot readObject

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am trying to Serialize Pair with following:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    if (mPair != null) {
        String first = mPair.first;
        String second = mPair.second;

        mPair = null;

        try {
            out.writeChars(first);
            out.writeChars("\n");
            out.writeChars(second);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        String first = in.readLine();
        String second = in.readLine();

        mPair = new Pair<String, String>(first, second);
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        mPair = new Pair<String, String>("", "");
    }
}
```

I debugged that `writeObject` was called properly me having 3 of my custom class objects, when my application went offscreen, but when I came back to application `readObject` never get's called.

Comment: Is that ObjectInputStream already conneted with a FileOutputStream like here? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm Note that im not sure how the whole process works on android based devices. Do you call those Methods or do you expcet the android SDK to do so? (if so: are you sure it does that?)

Comment: I have implemented serialization for Rect the same way, and it works properly.

Comment: Sorry i am no help then :(

Comment: post your complete class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that this simple solution seems to work:

```
public class SerializableStringPair extends Pair<String, String> implements
    Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SerializableStringPair(String first, String second) {
        super(first, second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two additional things

- You don't need a special code to serialize or de-serialize a class with just two strings. This is in the standard behavior. Just declare as `implements Serializable`  as you did and that's it.
- the code in your question contains an error: the second string has no newline at the end. When reading that with `readLine`, the serialization must get confused.

Comment: Thanks for comments, the thing here was that Pair is not Serializable, Strings were not the problem.